# Primefaces: RadioButtons stop working when using value property

Tags: jsf, primefaces, radio-button

I'm using Primefaces, and I need to create radio groups in each row of dataTable, so I'm trying to connect separate groups. I use widgetVar property to do so:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="first" widgetVar="connect">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="false" />                   
</p:selectOneRadio>

<p:selectOneRadio id="second" widgetVar="connect">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="true"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

It's working fine, when I check one, the other unchecks itself. 
The problem shows up when I try to attach a default value by adding value property like this:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="first" value="false" widgetVar="connect">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="false" />                   
</p:selectOneRadio>

<p:selectOneRadio id="second" value="false" widgetVar="connect">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="true"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Now It's set radio element named false to checked, but when I check the other, the first one stays checked. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: i think that you shouldnt use the same widgetVar for different components. try setting a different var for each `selectOneRadio`. you should incude your items with `selectItem` not with different `selectOneRadio`

Comment: I have to do it in deifferent selectOneRadio because it will be in different column in dataTable